# TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function in thymeleaf

Tags: jquery, thymeleaf

jQuery date picker is not working

Here is my html

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html layout:decorator="layout" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
        <head>
        <title>Tables | Bootstrap 3.x Admin Theme</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
            src="/js/twitter-bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
            src="/js/bootstrap-admin-theme-change-size.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/DT_bootstrap.js"></script>

        <!-- Bootstrap -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen"
            href="/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" />

        <!-- Bootstrap Admin Theme -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen"
            href="/css/bootstrap-admin-theme.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen"
            href="/css/bootstrap-admin-theme-change-size.css" />

        <!-- Datatables -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="/css/DT_bootstrap.css" />


        <!-- Jquery -->
        <link rel="stylesheet"
            href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>


        <script type="text/javascript">
            function notify() {
                alert("Notify called");
                $("#datepicker").datepicker();
            }
            $(function() {
                alert("hi");
                $("#datepicker").datepicker();
            });
        </script>
       </head>


           <body>
           <div>
            <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="endDate"
                                    onkeyup="notify()" />
            </div>
            </body>
```

I tried several solutions, which are there in stackoverflow,  but none of them are working...

do I need to use jquery in another way  because of thymeleaf?

Please help me out...

Comment: datepicker can be initialized only on page load

Comment: Please post relevant code only..why are you using notify() function?

Comment: Try including jQuery files before bootstrap js files.

Comment: tried all, but same result :(

Comment: Actually My application is using some predefined template for UI, so in the template there is a one  file, layout.html, This file is the basic one i.e in each and every page this layout.html will  be included.

In layout.html they are using jquery1.8 version, so I removed jquery reference in my html page...


So, its worked

Answer (score 2):

Put this script file

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

at the top of all other js files.

Answer (score 1):

If you load jQueryUI through Google, make sure the jQueryUI CSS theme has the same version as the jQueryUI library.

For example: like this,

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
            href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [Thymeleaf documentation about inline javascript](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#script-inlining-javascript-and-dart). You should use the following (best at the end of the page before `</body>`). From what I recall wrapping the javascript in `/*<![CDATA[*/` and `/*]]>*/` is required.

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
    /*<![CDATA[*/

    $(function () {
        $("#datepicker").datepicker();
    });

    /*]]>*/
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Drop the function initiate datepicker at page ready

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});
```

Comment: what is the diff between $(function() {}) and $(document).ready(function(){}) ??

Comment: the first is a shorter version of the second :)