# Thymeleaf + Spring MVC - selected date field on HTML5 is null on controller

Tags: html, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

The following input field for a date object works, apparently, nicely. But when it reaches the controller, the value for `executionDate` is null.

```
<form role="form" action="#" th:object="${pojo}" th:action="@{/scheduler/create}" method="post">
<div class="col-lg-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-10" >
    <div class="well with-header">
        <div class="header">
            <label th:for="datepicker0">Execution Date: </label>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group input-group">
            <input id="datepicker0" type="text" name="executionDate" th:field="*{executionDate}" class="form-control"></input>
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></span>                               
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
// rest of the page
</form>
```

Relevant part of controller is:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/scheduler/create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String createSchedulerPost(@Valid  @ModelAttribute("pojo") SchedulerPojo pojo, BindingResult result, ModelMap model) {

    System.out.println(pojo.getDescription());
    System.out.println(pojo.isRecurrent());
    System.out.println(pojo.getExecutionDate());
    System.out.println(pojo.getStartDate());
    System.out.println(pojo.getTerminationDate());
    System.out.println(pojo.getFailStrategy());
    (...) // I'm just verifying whether the SchedulerPojo pojo object has values for now...
}
```

The SchedulerPojo DTO is:

```
public class SchedulerPojo {

    private String id;

    private String description;

    private Date executionDate;

    private boolean recurrent;

    private Date startDate; 

    private Date terminationDate;

    private SchedulerFailStrategy failStrategy;

    // other attributes, getters and setters
}
```

Other, fields as the description String and recurrent boolean checkbox inputs return the given value on the HTML.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Can you please paste your controller code? Of course in your html you use `th:object` in the same `<form>`? And if you create datepicker object with inline js you escape code like in [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30757479/1501661)?

Comment: Yes, the `th:object="${pojo}"` reference is atop the `<form>`. Editing the question now.

Comment: Check if any value is sent to your controller (using for example firebug).

Comment: Some values, namely String description and the booleans, are printed out correctly by the controller...

Comment: Yes, but maybe there's a value sent to controller, but then `java.util.Date` constructor cannot handle this value? For now I only guess that problem is not in controller, but 1) the field is always empty so form sends `null`
2) there's a js problem with datepicker lib you use
3) some bizzare value for this field is sent to controller

Comment: It's the damned detepicker js lib... off geting a new one!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109598/discussion-between-iwo-kucharski-and-gtludwig).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Thymeleaf+Spring tutorial](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html#inputs) `th:field` generates code the same as you set `id` and `name` tags:

```
<input type="text" th:field="*{datePlanted}" />
```

Equivalent code :

```
<input type="text" id="datePlanted" name="datePlanted" th:value="*{datePlanted}" />
```

Maybe you need to remove `id=datepicker0` to `executionDate` and bind the `class` on datepicker?

```
<input class="date" type="text" th:field="*{executionDate}" class="form-control"></input>
...
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.date').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'});
    });
</script>
```